# Make Discord bot only react to a specific command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

If I use

```
if message.content.startswith('!skip'):
            await message.channel.send("meow meow meow")
```

and type !skip my bot reacts, but it would also react if I type !skip123.
How can I make my bot only react to !skip and nothing else?

Comment: try `message.content == '!skip'` instead of `message.content.startswith('!skip')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your existing `message.constant` string with `message.content == '!skip'` instead and if that doesn't work make sure you have no aliases even though I doubt it.

Comment: my bad i meant *content*